# How to detect if the computer is receiving data from a website or I.P address

Tags: java, networking

I would like my Java application to detect whether the computer is receiving data from a particular website (it could check for incoming data from a list of website I.P addresses I provide, for example). I don't need or care about what are the contents of the data - I only want to know whether the machine is getting data from those websites either by a web browser or some application.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share any Java code with us?  Either you can read data from a URL or you can't.

Comment: Is there an issue with using a tool such as Wireshark?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hi Tim - I don't have any sort of code - I'm just curious about this functionality. I know how to read data from an URL, but I don't know if Java can "detect" if the machine is somehow receiving data from that URL (like imagine Chrome is opening that URL)

Comment: Did you look at HttpHeaders interface?

Comment: @YiminRong I have not - I will take a look. I am not quite sure how would that help me monitor incoming traffic to the computer, though.

Comment: @JoeC I wanted to know if Java could achieve that same functionality. It's not that I need a tool to do this.

Comment: This is platform dependent. If I get you right, you want to sniff on _any_ incoming traffic to the _whole machine_, is that correct?

In this case, you need a driver that hooks into the network stack of the os. there are tools like ngrep for unix-based systems or npcap for windows which could provide some api. maybe that's where you want to go for.

Answer (score 0):

The native PCAP libraries are able to capture and send packets coming across your network interface.  I've only ever used it in a C++ context, but a quick Google search tells me that there are Java wrappers around these libraries.  (I cannot vouch for the quality of any of these libraries, though.)